# Is there a way to draw rectangles and/or squares with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code and would like to draw rectangles or squares in the figure/plot that is created. I was thinking that importing the Rectangle library would help, but so far it is showing a blank figure.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
  
  
# The image
X = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)
  
# highlight some feature in the
# middle boxes.
fig = plt.figure()
  
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
#ax.imshow(X, cmap = plt.cm.gray,
          #interpolation ='nearest')
ax.add_patch( Rectangle((0.1, 0.1),
                        .45, .45,
                        fc ='none', 
                        ec ='orange',
                        lw = 10) )
ax.add_patch(Rectangle((0.1, 0.1),
                       .8, .8,
                       fc = 'none',
                       ec = 'b',
                       lw = 10) )
plt.title("Rectangles")

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim([1.2, 2.5])
ax.set_ylim([1.5, 3.7])

plt.xlabel("x - axis")
plt.ylabel("y - axis")

  
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Output2: Does not have the range of 1  to 3 in Y-axis nor 1 to 3 in x-axis.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this as caused by a typo / not reproducible. You have set `xlim` and `ylim` to dimensions that exclude the positions of the rectangles. Comment out `ax.set_xlim([1.2, 2.5])` and `ax.set_ylim([1.5, 3.7])` and the code works without issue. [Code and Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLEnK.png)

Comment: How do you draw rectangles with ranges set by xlim and ylim though

Comment: You define the coordinates of the rectangle correctly. See [`matplotlib.patches.Rectangle`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html)

Comment: I mean the range is from 0 to 1 in x-axis and 0 to 1 in y - axis, but I need these ranges to be longer like 1 to 3 in x-axis and 1 to 3 in y-axis.

Comment: xlim and ylim adjusts the range of the axis, not the positions of the rectangle. As already stated, review the documentation for `Rectangle` and correctly specify the x and y coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
  
  

X = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)
  

fig = plt.figure()
  
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)


plt.title("Rectangles")

rect1 = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((1.3,1.6), 1.1, 2, color='blue', fc = 'none',lw = 2)
rect2 = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((1.5,1.8), .65, 1.6, color='orange',fc = 'none', lw = 2)

ax.add_patch(rect1)
ax.add_patch(rect2)


plt.xlim([1.2, 2.5])
plt.ylim([1.5, 3.7])

plt.xlabel("x - axis")
plt.ylabel("y - axis")

  
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).